Single spa Error Cannot use import statement outside a module while running root config
https://github.com/donexfience/MF_Testing_debug_purpose
when i running my root config after installing by create-single-spa --moduleType root-config commmand.After this i started my root config and i go to browser i see the error showing donexfdz-root-config-root-config.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at donexfdz-root-config-root-config.js:1:1)
im working on this for a week . I tried to change the webpack to emit commonjs that also didnt work by changing the

i attached a photo my code can you check please

i attached the photo as a link at the begining of my question is that possiblle to you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79072812/single-spa-error-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-while-running-root?noredirect=1#comment139426136_79072812

ok then how i show my code to you

https://github.com/donexfience/MF_Testing_debug_purpose  this will help you this is my github repo

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think he is asking about creating a single spa root-config using the create-single-spa cli. With the updated version 5, when a root config app is generated, it includes a welcome app but overall the app does not work throwing the error above in the description. This is also a problem I am stuck with. The default imports use SystemJs. Not sure what is the problem.

I do recommend going back to version 4.1.6 since many are facing the same issue. Also, you might face issue of default welcome app not working, simply go back to the ejs file and change its version from 3.0.0 to 2.0.0 and it will work

in the ejs file which version i ineed to chaange i will give my inde.ejs file here
<% if (isLocal) { %>

<% } %>

I was able to fix this bug by downgrading to version 4.1.6 of create-single-spa. I recommend that you do the same, surely in versions later than 5.X this problem will be solved.
